# Using datetime to get current date in android API level issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-support-library

My build.gradle configurations are as below.

```
const val MIN_SDK_VERSION = 21
    const val TARGET_SDK_VERSION = 26
    const val COMPILE_SDK_VERSION = 28
    const val BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION = "28.0.3"
```

I am trying to use LocalDateTime.now() in my code but it displays a warning in the code saying my minimum sdk version is 21 and LocalDateTime.now() is available only in API level 28.  I guess I may have to use support library to support this. Any pointers on how can I proceed using LocalDateTime.now() with the help of support library.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Java8 `java.time` on Android API levels older than 28, you can use ThreeTen Backport. In particular, you should use the Android adaptation ThreeTenABP that you can find [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).